# German word for ‘understocked’

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Is there a German word for *understocked*? If not, what phrase would be the best translation?

*Understocked* in the context that for example a supermarket does not have some products which are usually offered.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/to+be+understocked.html and https://browse.dict.cc/english-german/understock.html and http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/englisch-deutsch/understocked

Comment: to anwser you more spefic, you may want ot add the context you wish to use your question in by editing your question or add a comment.

Comment: "Ausverkauft!" means to have not a single pice anymore now - where there was some before. To prevent teasers the german law system sais the dealer is bound to his offers, sometimes good deals are low in quantity like "while stocks last" (Nur solange Vorrat reicht!) or summer sale. To allow such deals they must write "Nur solange Vorrat reicht!" to the deals and "Ausverkauft!" if there is not one anymore. "Ausverkauft" does not give a hint if there are orders at this time to support more items like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I throw another proposal into the ring:

> Bei Produkt xxx gibt es Lieferengpässe

This leaves open, where in the supply chain the bottleneck lies, but exactly this makes the phrase attractive for the shopkeeper, who did not order on time.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no word for that in german.

However, the best translation would probably be:

> nicht genug Ware auf Lager haben

or

> zu geringe Vorräte halten

Comment: maybe `unterbeliefert`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context

> unterversorgt

could also be an alternative.